# How to judge the quality of my own paper?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate, publishers

I am a B.Tech student in my final year, and am interested in publishing a paper. I have read a few articles in IEEE transactions and ACM transactions on my topic of interest, Software Engineering, and thought I can also produce such an idea. This semester I worked on a project under a professor in my institute, and I have written a paper based on my findings. My question is how can I judge the quality of the paper I have written? I want to find the perfect place to publish it, but don't want get demoralized by sending it to a top publisher and getting rejected. I should add that I don't think that my professor will be much help in determining the quality of the paper because I fear the professor knowledge is very  old and outdated and doesn't have any idea of current research.

Comment: I am sorry to say but I do not think your English are  good enough for writing a research paper. So, you need someone more senior to proofread and correct your paper (or more likely to write it from scratch)

Comment: I think when you say "journal written by you" you mean "paper written by you".  The journal is the organization which publishes paper or articles.  So in other words, you have written a **paper** and want to know how to judge its quality.  Unfortunately there are no easy answers and I think that you need to find a mentor with experience in the field.  If not your current advisor, then some other experienced researcher whom you trust.

Comment: @Alexandros for English,i have experts...

Comment: Why exactly don't you think your professor would be of help? That would otherwise be the default answer here.

Comment: I find it a little odd that on the one hand you're uncertain about your ability to evaluate your work, and on the other hand you seem very confident that your advisor doesn't know enough to evaluate your work.

Comment: "*don't want get demoralized by sending it to a top publisher and getting rejected*" - ability to deal with rejection and failure is arguably one of the most critical skills of an academic.

Comment: @Suresh basic fundamental are on the fingertips of my professor, but he in unable to comment to my work. He is not very much into research work.

Comment: @Alexandros The irony. What you stated is correct; agreed. But the irony...

Comment: I don't believe this question can be answered.  Yes there are a few basics one must have in a good paper but at the end of the day it comes down to the taste and mindset of reviewers.  Many seminal papers have been rejected initially and did not appear in supposedly top venues.  No doubt there are many poor papers been published by the transactions for example.  Having a supervisor who has a track record in these journal is key so you get a paper that looks and feel like it belongs.  After that it's a matter of luck and maybe your reputation.

Comment: You should read papers in the field and compare your paper with some of them. If your idea is good and it hasn't been explored before, your paper will have a few revisions and the quality of your writing style shall improve, leading to publication. However, I advise to talk to your peers, TA or professors about, since they will see the paper in a more professional way and maybe proofread it. Good luck!

Comment: @ Superbest have a good point. The ability to pass over failures, negative referee reports, good ideas which doesn't work as planned is very important.

Comment: @PanglossianOporopolist some people have _one_ English, others have _several_? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your adviser is a coauthor, he has to agree with whether the paper is suitable for submission to a particular journal.

Otherwise, you could judge the quality of your paper by comparing it with published papers in the journal you intend to submit your paper to. However, I recommend asking for other people's opinion about the paper; this would be people you know, who have had some publication experience.

Is there an upcoming conference which you can submit your paper to? It is a good idea to submit the paper to a conference first.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking about SEDE 2014 
http://theory.utdallas.edu/SEDE2014/

Comment: @CyberBoy SEDE has a very bad reputation: http://sede-2011.blogspot.com/2011/09/fake-paper-accepted-by-sede-2011-20th.html

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to submit your manuscript to a pre-print repository and see if you get some comments on it. Of course, you should take into account the fact that not all journals publish works that have already been posted in a repository. Additionally, you could also send a pre-submission inquiry to some journal editors with a brief summary of your research. If an editor shows interest in your paper, you can then submit it to the journal.

Comment: "not all journals publish works that have already been posted in a repository" which journal please? if a journal is not accepting preprint versions to be submitted online prior to peer review then is violating copyright laws. The leading journals are open to arxiv and other repositories.

Comment: @Mikey Mike: Wikipedia has this list of journals by their preprint policies.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_journals_by_preprint_policy  According to this list, there are a few journals that are incompatible with accepting preprint versions and others which are unclear about whether they would be willing to accept them.